# Windows - edit shortcut options programmatically

Tags: c#, windows, command-line, cmd

I have a console application (.bat file) which starts in a console window. I have a shortcut to this app on my desktop, which contains several properties which I need to change programmatically (in example font of this specific window).

How can I do this? The best option for me would be to do it using cmd.exe commands, or using .net environment, is that even possible?

Comment: look at `http://support.microsoft.com/kb/242297` and `http://support.microsoft.com/kb/244677`